# stylelint rule blacklist specific selector

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint, stylelint

This is regarding `stylelint`.

I am looking for a solution to blacklist use of specific selectors like

```
html[dir="rtl"]
{
    //some css
}
```

There is a rule to block specific property [Link.](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/property-blacklist/)

But there is no rule to block use of particular selector.

Is there any way I can tweak previous available rule to blacklist above selector??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to configure existing rules to achieve what you want.

However, I believe you have two choices to resolve this:

1. [Create an issue](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues) and request this feature. I think there is a good case to add something like a `selector-blacklist` rule and a `selector-whitelist` rule to stylelint.
2. [Write your own stylelint plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/) to disallow this specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly are you trying to disallow. All Tags selectors? All Attributes selectors for the `html` tag specifically? All attributes selectors completely?

You can use this rule, if you want to specifically not allow the `[dir]` selector ([see demo](https://stylelint.io/demo/#N4Igxg9gJgpiBcIAWAXAtgGwNpQJYCcBeAHRHxQ1IF0ACYYgOxpsgwn3hvxigG5GAvoxAAaEAGcAngxQBDAB4Jw48aPAQGAM1wBzJfSY1S+AK4YY40pwPNmpWQwYQ5KXBoC0T9yYYBrJwDuDFY0KKYwIoy2RiCyKO6m5p4Q3n6BwQih4ZGGdiAARmxgvsnuMGgADiiSIWEmEVG2pKzspbgMAG6yGLhQ7kgw8rXZjXmQaGgwMqXlVTWZdQ25MWAm4igQaO4V+BAVMOSSpWi4Ku067l347po+YK4aw-U50aSwYBiy+HFuDO6FEGKpSgJgqPTAcRg7lW602212+3IuAsTyWrxA70+3wefwBQK8ILBuAhKChOz2B1cKMyWFGtkWL2idDp6N0Tm4IVpyyZKw04hgq1cHShhPBkPE7gCuBQSHceE0mgOU3iXQw9UsIBZtioWqEyyojLymK+Pw8eJKXnESHYMocfXJiOq7ggwvw+F61M4DLppE0GnimlkJwwRwJoLFpM8Qc9WWePpAfumgeDoZSJzODAuOimB2JNyDuBD7l8MEkAXYUFRhpitwY91+0O6YFKPnEFVkYB4zsRcXYVfjtfrHh6DBgX3cOm+eGVpScDHWdq+fTw3CHGS9I2WvruOJbaQgQX7W5AJckmm+k3+RQtKVFxMh7n55nu7A1G7jx9P5+jcoFWNNfxeLglQ2g4KBHuikx4LINxjigJjcFGl5eD4-gHuusZok0IAMNGfSTr07hfGOEpAZ03S9BB2EEhYnYMHgmaPvsYC4NoLHVFReRhkSJJQnE7jARUNoJGYMbese3ERlCT4Chs+Bvph1akF4sxOuIEAIZ2nExCp8hhDB-InC087acpKTtKqhFQBphTSZ8VrQpskwyAp4nomRln2hA4jSg2-GCcJiQwKZOHmW6MA6GY44BEg0oWO2WkLJu6IOpSqapGhh5JR+6IyS+1wVPyJjWdC9mkSkqHpCFeVydsRUlTA5jOfEKH7ll75YXkNWtNU+x7plGFcjyblMjYPIxGy7DBTSWrojCGxbI15TKhqs00Dq3I0Hq0QGvG6zuoxXijgEI7TR1SkgD40r9VV2WdTE3QVEgMGqvUyQuL8nJaqQiJ0XI2akNWzBjTypCDJ2VQAAoIpSyIKUN415HsHbSvMa0bTy23ahd-FBWUlROqd-wwH6HIzZt9gYAEsiSBqQPMpteTgzAVRfYz2HmuYKhEZopLXOIP64ZenMWHTa15No8ktRYpKVpq7O7ezpCTWTnAI4j9i8wcjkTMqpDo7qdKK+iuOiUhUIQvyISkGwAQHID8am0kQvSQlfFa-g1uxFTNMSj5mZJKdDvHk7UJeMK9GtDsJO4EMd04-EeOGcSEBsIBMAne07t8173TU7TwfouapXeec-zfJ2+NzO4RP5CTU1e6OrqFxz14l-7Fz5BXYcZ0Tsge7nPsF6I8bFx8peMV3HY95no7E6TZ0PUPEpoGYrg11nLd5GPbAd+X09MQfdcL4P+d++cgebyPx7FxSDBl1PlfHX3A+ZJTZ-uKvGDr0H19F23d8H7d0PpXfuOc37ew-h3S+o4t4xFvvse+k9gFtiPvXVWS8z5wOaKnVog5dxOA+o8CBaBoAHAyBdFo1wBjyEbFbCBtt7Z-2wlQ-ogwa5TB0DKL2VobTYPULraYqkji13QYvdW2E86+zgcDNaYN5AQ3AuTRGEsCDrE8DLHg+sFb0zyCrcR4sYjrEkOYEc8RxhoDtKtBWht9SUKcjOGKcVUGV3aD5WAp9pHMLGGsBa8IKSHCroTLO88G7KKZO-Lx9MQYRJAMzVm4SNaxA9tCXxcJUqHBkbEyW6jRzrC0fLRGxtxrKx0OyAx7M8hgO1hYvW3iSkgDcR6R8F8oS12vNooptidqULSVsKCuAYLthQHzQa30QAAD0AAUWAYIAC8qCzPcHMgADO4AAnFQAAVAASime4JZqyNlUAANQ7K2QAEiyTEyCotZAAwgQAUXkMxWWLA+k0AGbIGgABHeo+BJA0BdqECANA640BLPkWQ+Q6HTW6djeM810kw0CcM0ZbNQaTJmfMxZ8y1mbN2fsw5+LTnnKufU2RSsQCTBUPcxepBnmvJ4O82EaAaAZOqEC6MIKwUwAhTAKFMLLZws2ljZgxSjR-hNLuKFjEXHZyYZwZSMBm71LeFK7EDZZUXHlaEjBkTh4XWNJqs0bdk7GQ0bPBVnsIFSNpp-NeuAN6wLVRiDVAEryAhKOa3BfxdXVJtUqyBvsWkBzaVfI17qZVmvKCnNOICoTHzCUGpuTDI0fGlVqs1rTnVQksbQ41AEFIAEZ03-mjV69w+lCxlx9WnTxhr4yForfiFI3AQT0TAjXDQOhnr0X8Y6OGIVm0Ngtc-EJAaG0r0dbm-hI6PAWv9a-INdrz5htna6+dfxF1uz1fSnCKq01NqjQ2YRua90Ytiau65ci4kKJZkotWhjNZ81-Bmk1FDn0JjUdLfJct0a6ImmU5NNAJGYoDTrZqWTWTzmadA8Nc9zSdPGhjJkYr1oXUTAGAsRYXbuD+c4GMBqJQxSVAkAUDj6IFMwzuUdTkYLjrnpO21y8HXfydb-GjdZdwWIMru5jK7WPwY3VxtckG+NoJPhA1NNrRO7nzUEkRWcFIrLkw2PDwqvaMNkwOWjHh2zcBkAMfkpFe4hKaR4ljH8v4-wjbp7jDYDPKmMxYBNAlYOWZTYe-mObOP2bEwhDA+GTCEYUsR-h+CGxONJEu8BgmsGuqQG9WAk4YBh2cABXOYb+EBXIO9TLED9rnBy1RmQBXOAACYLpfgvNJJa+V8s4i9r9ZUdLUhcxI9KWKfxTzlnwH0DQRYkOupq9GUiP40XkMveiaZhzcXLJJYSg5eLjlnMuTeqlNKBYPKDYy2SzLRuTC5UdjYvL+WCthch6I6GJUxHMJmGUyyDgpFatKEKCmz2nRLRdBTRN7tcKQCEYtFXVPxi+bBOICELa+rcwJzBUSwc8EGRD+CiEd2SZA8q1VP2kcwUVJDxCGnZD0KDdp-h4P8eo7DoLFIEdrIFW4NoOO51EfQRR1D7YxEjMWFc7qiz+6ZPk9x+zxC3xMxQgCb2fm-Hl3w8bceCncEOdi+zN2A4Uu3NJv1cG+Xty2d-IOEp9RvHLUvzi3L6d7GROs+RwbgFG9jf0dh7L4joadAwOmjj-X-yjfmKd7qrXAvvP8JUgTI4OT4i-xZxJFIMBU6SlijFt2IUvDpj3lMAbmhHwaXwE-MzLro-uRMGgOu1xzCyAYhcOZz2p0h+L6Xz+Ch4QClOJ9TIAAWC6DB6-ay8NWkcVfnuuWSthDlRxNMMIPEe48Y-Sh06joz2OIU8afZCYH6bkjWM2Y43ZzaNzsLxMfaBr9EeNF-qu0yW7rJgMYLA1elJtSZAX52vC8VF1urXDiGEXA+QTCRjw3gALBgIwn0D0OsF7CuPwh-kRCMu6L-pGI-CWCgH7Luvzo3MHq6tAV-nAX-hLj2LVLFoqjpBge-vVrVNgT-rgWrtiK0AHmIugdjntGQa0BQfAVCARjFrXpgcwdcBmtzJNvgGMhTFinNsSscktmIZsmtuStEreltnSl7HtvcMynweIDQB-jyuCpCtCpdoUmhkbKQc+LVOMPkO0BroQYGhblATwTrKYbhAQbuuvlZgjseNAbAOIHRFAF2iYWYbVEdB4PKtVDYYRAIUIZirNjipIdsnsstgtqtmShtkkvITtjEEoW8r0OoTwZoXytoUKsTiKpjAYUwUYa0GAX7hMAxvntalwYYbJKUacOUZYprvQdJiQcUXUdcB9mHrmiprUQ1uHBngvjHMzopO0f0c4I1m3kGuMGCIMNYSUQVPVCkKoboaTlPjpq4TYYVDAMVMsWVJzoZjKDzigQfGga0YwZsQsXVDsQ1E1DOBPmsXbBsblFsUsWUHcdMGOhlk1hAtZCYLZPMR0VWpIH1A8XdusVAdaOQH2vaCik6F4O2j4F4dMK9GJCPl1N-oxBwURhiDZOYPwldOYvkVphCa6qicWKWH1n0GCTbKSRdOSWUeJqbhOi7jrpbrZi6vSd0G9IySbhYVOm7h7vwgyQ0UyXQVJl5hceiCKeol0dXF9iEKDseOSQMZHAzsMaiI0HqAICAAIEAA)):

```
"selector-attribute-name-disallowed-list": "dir",
```